# How to get a list of IP Addresses in a Network

Tags: c#

How to get a list of IP Addresses/hostnames  in a Network
using c#

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a program that does exactly that. I have it at home :(

It uses the [Ping](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.ping.aspx) and [NetworkInterface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkinterface.aspx) classes, to find it through brute force.

I basically iterate through all interfaces, generate all addresses that are valid for the interface network mask, and ping them asynchronously.

It's simple but not perfect. If there are interfaces in the network that don't reply to pings, they won't be listed. This could be the case if there are firewalls active (like Windows Firewall which blocks pings by default).

Oh, yes, it's terribly exhaustive.

**EDIT:**
Even though [Mitch Wheat's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239148/how-to-get-a-list-of-ip-addresses-in-a-network/1239170#1239170) is not what you asked, it reminded me you could use [Dns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.aspx) to resolve the hostnames of all those addresses..

Answer (score 1):

Something to note however:
By default, modern Windows systems do not respond to pings (e.g. XP with the firewall on), so the approach proposed won't work reliably.

The technique I use (albeit not on Windows or C#) is to ping the whole subnet, then look in the ARP cache (as the machines will still respond to ARP requests.)

Not sure how one would accomplish this in C# though.

Comment: +1. Very good idea. Will edit my answer to make the Windows Firewall thing more explicit.

Answer (score 0):

CodeProject has a pretty crude way of achieving this using the DOS `net view` command:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/ipaddresses.aspx

Comment: Ouch. That's even worse than my solution.